# Mock a complex api call

Tags: java, spring

I have some problemi understanding spring `@MockBean` in complex api call:

```
serviceCommunication.callAPI(HttpMethod.POST,
                                    ServiceCommunication.TokenType.TokenTypeApplication,
                                    "document-service",
                                    URIConstants.CREATE_DOCUMENT,
                                    docDTO,
                                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<ApiResultResponse<String>>() {
                                    });
```

I mock before the test with:

```
when(serviceCommunication.callAPI(eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                any(ServiceCommunication.TokenType.class),
                eq("document-service"),
                eq(URIConstants.CREATE_DOCUMENT),
                any(),
                eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ApiResultResponse<String>>() {}))).thenReturn(new ApiResultResponse<>(documentID));
```

but I got a null result, where I wrong?

Comment: I have discovered that the call work when is called in the same thread where mock is created but not when it is called in separate thread.

Comment: Your problem could be the last ligne of your matchers

eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ApiResultResponse<String>>() {}))

You specified that it's eq to a new instance of ParameterizedTypeReference then call with an other

Have you tried an any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class) instead?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved, I have mocked the task executor, the problem was when mock bean is called in another thread